# ELSE must be uppercase but its already uppercase

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm trying to writte a IF condition on robot framework

Something as simple as:

```
*** Variables ***
${VAR} = 1
${VAR2} = 2
*** Keywords ***
Compare vars
    IF  ${VAR} <= ${VAR}
        log   Passed
    ELSE
        log   Failed
    END
```

And I get the error that ELSE must be uppercase following an opening 'IF' but it's already uppercase.
I've tried restarting pycharm.
I've tried SeleniumLibrary and RPA.Brownser.Selenium
I've tried adding END and the end of the IF but it then complains about the END not beeing uppercase aswell.

As it is right now, that bit of code has worked at least 2 times and go through the rest of code I have but 95% of times I get the error described.

Comment: What robot version are you using?

Comment: Version 5.0.1 (Python 3.11.4 on win32)

Comment: Can you modify your code to be executable and reproduces your error? Your current code does not define variables correctly, and no test case would run your keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The source of truth is always a run of `robot` from the command line/terminal/shell.

In your case looks like an error in the IDE.

Your complete test sample, is OK in [RIDE](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE), for example:

```
| *** Variables *** |
| ${VAR}         | 1 |
| ${VAR2}        | 2 |

| *** Test Cases *** |
| Compare |
|    | Compare vars |

| *** Keywords *** |
| Compare vars |
|    | IF | ${VAR} <= ${VAR} |
|    |    | Log | Passed |
|    | ELSE |
|    |    | Log | Failed |
|    | END |
```

Comment: I always run my tests on the terminal. for example: "robot -d results tests/amazon.robot"

Answer (score 0):

It seems your example code is just a random scratch as I can spot 2 flaws right away:

1. there must be at least 2 empty spaces between the '=' and values, else this will fail:

```
*** Variables ***
${VAR} = 1
${VAR2} = 2
```

2. you compare VAR with itself:

```
IF  ${VAR} <= ${VAR}
```

While this will not result in an error, why would you wanna do that?

Anyway, I suggest you run your case with [TRACE log level](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#log-levels) and then check your log file where you should be able to see what exactly is being passed into your problematic keyword.

If it won't do, please provide a real example of your code as it is hard to draw any conclusion in respect of the error you stated.